# Spring Boot JPA : Autowired JPA repository is null

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I'm programming a lib for the services / DAOs layer, trying to use Spring BOOT. I want to use JPA repositories, and will probably need to use JDBC as well.

So, I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/), modifying it a bit but can't get it to work.  The repository I want is not accessible through `@Autowired` annotation.

Here are my files, starting with `pom.xml`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My main class :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "politik.commons")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

A bean :

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Column(name="hash")
    private String hash;

    @Column(name="url")
    private String url;

    @Column(name="url_source")
    private String urlSource;

    @Column(name="html")
    private String html;
}
```

The repository :

```
@Repository
public interface IArticleDAO extends JpaRepository<Article, Long> {
}
```

The test controller :

```
@RestController
public class TEstCtrl {

    @Autowired
    IArticleDAO articleDAO;

    public TEstCtrl () {
        System.out.println("coucou hiboux");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String test() {
        String t = new String();
        for (Article article : articleDAO.findAll())
        {
            t = t + article.getUrl() + "\n";
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

And finally, the stack trace :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [politik.commons.dao.IArticleDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
```

What am I missing ?

Thank you !

Comment: What packages are all these classes in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your Article entity doesn't have a Long Id field. The second generic property in JpaRepository  corresponds to the type of the id of the entity the repository manages. Change your Article class as follows and it should work:

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @bm1729, thanks replying me. I modified Article to this :
```@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id; ```

But I have the same issue. I guess I havn't to update my database table to make this error disappear, am I right (I will have to of course if I want to request)

Comment: Other things to check: IArticleDAO is in a suitable package that can be picked up by the autoscan. I've never had to use the @ EnableJpaRespositories annotation and I don't annotate my repository interfaces. Try using @ SpringBootApplication instead of all those annotations on your Main class.

Comment: Thank you, the error disappeared, I can move on to next steps :)

Comment: If an answer helped you, @ogdabou, you should upvote it